# Upgrading from Django 1.6 (with south) to 1.8 doesn't modify 'last_login' on the user table

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south, django-1.8

I have upgraded from Django 1.6.5 (with south migrations) to Django 1.8. I have followed the instructions here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

So, I remove South, delete my previous migrations and run `python manage.py makemigrations` which makes a new migration file. Then I run `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` to fake the initial migration. Then I run `python manage.py migrate`.

It all runs fine with no errors.

I have a custom user model which inherits `AbstractBaseUser`. In Django 1.8 it seems there is a change to the `last_login` field where it is now able to accept a `null` value (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login).

The problem I have, is that the migration does not change the `last_login` field in the database table to accept null values. As a result, when I try and save I get a `IntegrityError` saying `(1048, "Column 'last_login' cannot be null")`.

How can I fix this? Do I need to manually change the field in the database, or is there a way to fix it with migrations?

**Edit**
When I run `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` the output is this:
Running migrations:

```
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying core.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying admin.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... FAKED
```

However, when I look in the database I still see `user_last_login` as not-null.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As noted in the [1.8 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#abstractuser-last-login-allows-null-values):

> If you are using a custom user model that inherits from `AbstractUser`, you’ll need to run `makemigrations` and generate a migration for your app that contains that model.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did do this already, in my edit above I added the output which contains the line `Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK`. If I am correct this is the migration that will perform the removal of the not null constraint, however it didn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to make sure the initial migrations match your database schema. Since you skipped Django 1.7, you'll have to edit the automatically generated initial migration for the app that contains your custom user model and remove the `null=True` attribute from the `last_login` field. Then you can generate a second migration which will remove the NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: How to remove the NOT NULL constraint?

Comment: @diofeher Open your `0001_initial.py` file and remove the `null=True` text from the `last_login` field on your model. Then run `makemigrations` again