# django IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'last_login' cannot be null")

Tags: mysql, django, migration

So I got this error, and looked at this stackoverflow question:
[django-registration (1048, "Column 'last_login' cannot be null")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847110/django-registration-1048-column-last-login-cannot-be-null)

So I went into the database and deleted the row with 0005_alter_user_last_login_null.py.

After I ran: python manage.py migrate it still didn't detect any new migrations.

How am I supposed to fix my database and make the user last_login optional? I thought there might be some way to reapply a previous migration but I couldn't get that to work. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix the database?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Output of python ./manage.py showmigrations auth

[X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages

Comment: Your question is unclear, Are you trying to detect migrations or fix an error? Please describe the issue you're trying to solve

Comment: @Sayse, thanks for your comment. I tried to clarify a bit, but I honestly don't know what it is I should do to fix the database. I'm really awful with this stuff.

Comment: Could post your "new migrations"? And then, I think you need to make a new migration to make the `last_login` optional rather than deleting old migration.

Comment: Please show the output of `./manage.py showmigrations auth`

Comment: @EdwinLunando, I read somewhere else that migration 0005 makes it optional

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all so much! With @Alasdair's suggestion I noticed that I simply needed to run that migration again, and was able to do so by running the command:

```
python manage.py migrate auth 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
```

It works now, thanks!